# mongoimport cannot find file in (public) GCS bucket

Tags: mongodb, google-cloud-storage, data-transfer

We have a newline delimited JSON file saved in a public bucket in GCS:

[image]

Shows as public to internet. Hopefully one of the following 3 links finds the JSON on your end:

- https://storage.googleapis.com/cbb-staging/division_info
- https://storage.cloud.google.com/cbb-staging/division_info
- gs://cbb-staging/division_info

We are trying to import this JSON into our MongoDB cluster using `mongoimport`. Our MongoDB URI string is correct, however we are struggling to point to the file in GCS.

- mongoimport --uri "mongodb+srv://UserName:Password@our-cluster.abcde.gcp.mongodb.net/dbname" --collection staging__text_export --drop --file https://storage.googleapis.com/cbb-staging/division_info
- mongoimport --uri "mongodb+srv://UserName:Password@our-cluster.abcde.gcp.mongodb.net/dbname" --collection staging__text_export --drop --file https://storage.cloud.google.com/cbb-staging/division_info
- mongoimport --uri "mongodb+srv://UserName:Password@our-cluster.abcde.gcp.mongodb.net/dbname" --collection staging__text_export --drop --file gs://cbb-staging/division_info

All 3 of these return the similar error `Failed: open https://storage.cloud.google.com/cbb-staging/division_info.json: no such file or directory`. We tried adding `.json` to the end of the file names and it did not help.

Is this possible to do?

Comment: that's not possible. `mongoimport` works only with local file or with some path to the file. You can create a network path by mapping GCP file storage, it may work.

Comment: is `https://storage.cloud.google.com/cbb-staging/division_info` not a path to the file? When I go to that URL a file downloads for me.

Comment: the protocol varies, mongoimport cannot pull the data over http/https. It needs network path or file path which follows different file protocol

Answer (score 0):

Here's a screenshot from MongoDB Atlas Support confirming what Rajdeep has said in the comments.

[image]